# Find out if there is a way to create BMI weight category variable

Tags: distributions, spss, curve-fitting, interpolation

I am working on a project and have to find a way to break my data into percentiles.
**The variables that I already have are gender, age in months and BMI. If I am able to calculate the percentile that each child falls into, I will then be able to label them as underweight, normal weight, overweight and obese.**

I would be using the following cutoff values:

> CDC Growth Charts 5th and 95th percentile
>
> BMI-for-age ≥ 95th Obesity
>    BMI-for-age ≥ 85th and < 95th Overweight
>    BMI-for-age < 5th Underweight

The previous links weren't working, so here are links to the growth charts for [boys (pdf)](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/set1clinical/cj41c023.pdf) and [girls (pdf)](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/set1clinical/cj41c024.pdf) if anyone isn't familiar with them.  These charts present contours of BMI percentiles (from the 5th through the 95th in irregular intervals) by age (for ages 24 to 240 months).

Can anyone suggest a simple and accurate way to use these charts to obtain the preceding classifications from my data?

Comment: *I posted on another forum but no one was able to help: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/53437-New-to-SPSS-want-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-way-to-create-BMI-category-variable?p=150054#post150054


*I also posted to http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/New-to-SPSS-want-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-way-to-create-BMI-weight-category-variable-td5724264.html#a5724265

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking, so I wanted to check the links to see whether they could clarify things ... but they do not work.  Please edit this question to explain what kind of data you have and why you need to break them into percentiles.

Comment: Categorization of BMI is invalid, and the use of percentiles for categorization defies the laws of physics.  Do you think that increasing BMI puts physical strain on the cardiovascular system or do you think that the number of other persons in the sample who have BMI lower than yours affects your cardiovascular system?  That is what is assumed when percentiling.

Comment: sorry, this was cut short, try this page http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/childrens_BMI/tool_for_school‌​s.html and adapt the formula from Excel for SPSS.  As Frank considers this approach to be invalid, perhaps he would contact CDC.

Comment: It is not clear that your question actually has anything to do w/ statistics per se. 1st of all, the charts you link to are for kids age 2+, but given your phrasing ("age in months"), I suspect you are working w/ infants. If these are the right charts (or you can get them), the procedure would be to print them out & use a ruler to make a crude interpolation.  If you could get the mathematical functions that those lines represent, you could use your age & BMI information to solve for the percentile w/ arithmetic. Either way, this isn't about statistics.

Comment: @gung Closely related issues were [discussed in meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/750) almost three years ago. Using a ruler is not an acceptable solution when there are more than a handful of records. The alternative is a computerized solution, which amounts to a request for help with acquiring and processing statistical data (and perhaps with the specialized task of interpolating values among smoothed empirical distributions): that seems on topic to me.

Comment: The CDC site has changed yet again!  Try this link http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/childrens_bmi/tool_for_schools.html and if not found search the CDC A-Z for body mass index, then look for the Children's BMI tool for schools, which is a quite complex Excel spreadsheet, that must presumably contain a formula that would do the job.  I haven't got Excel at home.  Alternatively, ask CDC how they calculate it.

Comment: @gung the kids are between the ages of 3 and 5, but the dataset provides me with the age in months.

Comment: @RobertJones I found the spreadsheet and it looks awesome but there are two problems that I am encountering. I need to enter Date of Birth and I currently have it as three separate variables on SPSS; day, month, and year. I'm sure that if I play around with it I can figure that one out. My second problem is that they ask for date of measurement but all I have is (age in months at time of assessment). If I add the (age in months) to the (date of birth) I'll be able to create the date of measurement variable.Is there a way to do that on SPSS?

Comment: The actual calculations in the spreadsheet are hidden in a table called [CDC 2000 reference] and formulas in a sheet called [Data].  The table summarizes the distributions by age (for each month) and sex in terms of three parameters: a weight scale $M$, a Box-Cox power $L$, and a final scale $S$. These convert a BMI into a z-score for the percentile.

Comment: To convert years, months and days to a date use the SPSS function DATE.DMY(day, month, year) which can be found in the
SPSS command syntax reference manual (available via SPSS help), with some examples of use. You can then use the DATESUM function in the form DATESUM(birthdate, months, "months"), see manual for examples of use.

Comment: @RobertJones It worked! Thank you so much. I managed to import the data into the table and now have all of the percentiles in an excel file. My next step is going to be to create a new variable using the percentiles and then breaking them into the overweight, underweight etc. categories as discussed before. I going to try to tackle this next bit on my own but definitely will be back if I need more help. Thank you again to everyone that contributed!

Comment: As this question was cross posted, you may be interested in the answer at http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/New-to-SPSS-want-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-way-to-create-BMI-weight-category-variable-td5724264.html.  Though I think the originator of the question has now found an acceptable way to solve her problem another way.

Comment: I think this question should be considered answered, as PRogman (not me) has provided a solution and good references at http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/New-to-SPSS-want-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-way-to-create-BMI-weight-category-variable-td5724264.html